# Checking if the HTTP response body is empty

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

What I am trying to achieve is to check if the body that is returned from the HTTP POST method in Logic App (which is a trigger) is empty or not.

[image]

I have tried to look for the answer in docs, but could not really find the right answer. Tried this, but this does not work either "empty(triggerBody())".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

To check if its empty or not use `empty(triggerBody())` in compose action then use this output inside the condition action(is equal to true).

[image]

**If true then its empty, if false its not empty.**

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@empty(triggerBody())",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {},
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@outputs('Compose')",
                                true
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```